# Bluetooth LE Tracking using Mac Packet Logger

Tags: ios, macos, bluetooth

I have an iPhone running the iBeacons API, and it is transmitting a BLE Signal. Is there any way for my Mac to actually pick up the existance of this signal using dev tools such as Packet Logger or Bluetooth Explorer?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Bluetooth Explorer. Under "Devices" you can find "Low Energy Devices", which is able to scan for LE devices, connect to them and write to them